# where is D3D11.h/lib for direcxt11.3

Tags: directx, version-control

I'm starting to see how to do multiview rendering from different view in one pass. This needs D3D11_FEATURE_DATA_D3D11_OPTIONS3 to be checked but the D11 sdk 11_0 don't know this flag and after a web search I can't get wher eto get d11.3 update (donwload .h and .lib I guess.

any link to help me for this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Where is the DirectX SDK?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-)

> Starting with Windows 8, the DirectX SDK is included as part of the Windows SDK.

So download the latest Windows SDK from Microsoft and you'll get updated DirectX headers and libs.

Comment: mmm let see that.

Comment: well after installing windows sdk I have finally d3d11_3 and more. but it seems that my old windows 8.1 with VS 2013 does not allow me to use D3D11_3 samples.

Comment: Is it possible to open an empty VS2013 project and feed it with the h/cpp files coming from the DX11 samples prepared for VS2015 or later?

Comment: The Windows 10 SDK is not officially supported for VS 2013, only the Windows 8.1 SDK. As DirectX 11.3 is only supported for Windows 10 or later, you should consider moving to a newer toolset.